# Partial Ordering of Vectors

Tags: c++, numpy, sorting, vector, partial-ordering

Given 5 vectors such as:

```
     X1   X2
    ---------
A = [51, 134]
B = [40, 110]
C = [41, 191]
D = [35, 198]
E = [30, 140]
```

I am trying to find similar vectors such as if `A[X1]>B[X1]` and `A[X2]>B[X2]`, we remove `B` and keep A as a 'good' vector. If `A[X1]>B[X1]` and `A[X2]<B[X2]` then we keep both of them. I've tried using cosine similarity between vectors but the results are incorrect. For example, the above vectors will have only 3 remaining 'good' vectors, `A,C,D`. Comparing each attribute and sorting column wise (partial ordering) is a way I am thinking of going with. But what if I have `d = 10` attributes? How to go about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think by what you mean from `A[Xi] > B[Xi]`, you actually mean `row[Xi] > next_row[Xi]`.

```
>>> A = [51, 134]
>>> B = [40, 110]
>>> C = [41, 191]
>>> D = [35, 198]
>>> E = [30, 140]

>>> arr = np.vstack([A, B, C, D, E])
>>> arr
array([[ 51, 134],
       [ 40, 110],
       [ 41, 191],
       [ 35, 198],
       [ 30, 140]])

>>> # (row_i[X1] > row_i+1[X1]) and (row_i[X2] > row_i+1[X2])
>>> cond1 = np.cumprod(arr[:-1] > arr[1:]).all(axis=1)
>>> cond1
array([ True, False, False, False])

>>> # (row_i[X1] > row_i+1[X1]) and (row_i[X2] < row_i+1[X2])
>>> cond2 = (arr[:-1, 0] > arr[1:, 0]) | (arr[:-1, 1] > arr[1:, 1])
>>> cond2
array([ True, False,  True,  True])

>>> cond1 | cond2
array([ True, False,  True,  True])

>>> arr[:-1][cond1 | cond2]
array([[ 51, 134],  # A
       [ 41, 191],  # C
       [ 35, 198]]) # D
```